# How to generate a file after grep just if it founds the content?

Tags: shell, grep

I'm doing this (e.g.:):

```
grep a text.txt > file.log
```

I can generate the file.log just if it founds the "a". Should I put it into a if? How?
Can someone please give me an example? At this time this is generating blank files.

Answer (score 6):

A simple workaround would be to say:

```
grep a text.txt > file.log || rm file.log
```

This would remove `file.log` if `grep` didn't find a match.  So you won't have blank files.

Answer (score 5):

```
awk '/a/{print >"file.log"}' text.txt
```

this command will create file.log if the file text.txt has a match with 'a'